# Формирование смс и открытие приложения для его отправки

Tags: android, sms

Возникла идея написания приложения, в которое хочу впихнуть возможность формирования смс-сообщения и открытия соответствующего приложения для его оправки. Подскажите, возможно ли это и где про это почитать. Так и не поняла как правильно у гугла об этом спрашивать)

Comment: >  Так и не **понял к**ак правильно у гугла
> об этом спрашивать)

Comment: @Gorets, исправила) но лучше бы чего-нить по делу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный способ - intent. (взято [здесь](http://www.androidsnippets.com/send-sms-via-intent):

```
Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("tel:100861"); // кому
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "shenrenkui"); // текст
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Пользователю будет показан стандартный на его телефоне интерфейс отправки смс (он может подредактровать, если что).

Другой способ заключается в использовании класса [SmsMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html).

Comment: @KoVadim, огромное спасибо за ответ. в ближайшее время попробую)

Comment: также, в стандартных демках, которые идут с sdk, есть примеры - sample/android-17/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/SmsMessagingDemo.java (вместо 17 можно подставить другие доступные числа, по версии апи).

Comment: Даже не знала о таком